# Brick labels to be printed

Tags: piece-information, storage, inventory

I am new to the LEGO "business". But I am building up my inventory, getting close to 100.000 pieces now, and before shooting off, I want to have my "system" organized. That also includes print off labels for every small part, to glue on the separate box/draw for item. This makes it easier, and more safe for proper work by several people, assuring that the right part is picked.

But, where do I find info about this? My wish is to print a few, important key words about the part - part.no., picture...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

[Tom Alphin has a template of labels](http://tomalphin.com/bricklabels) you can download and print with the appropriate label printer.

Sample:
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use [www.bricklabels.com](http://www.bricklabels.com/)

It allows you to select which parts you want to print and allows you to print the labels in your custom size, fitting the drawers perfectly.

[image]

Full disclosure: I made the app :-/, but it's free and open-source: https://github.com/Gottwik/legolabels

Comment: This looks great! Thanks for building this and sharing it here!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the encouragement. Let me know if something doesn't work or you would like more features.

Comment: Since you're already using the Rebrickable API, it would be cool if this imported a users parts so that they don't have to manually enter everything. If you include filtering, this could make it trivial to do something like print a label for every gear element that a user owns.

Comment: That's a good idea. I will sure implement this. I would often reprint labels when the container got too small as the amount of bricks increased or as I got some new parts, so it was always easy to just input the part id from the previous label and reprint it.

Comment: @MartinGottweis Just to point out, when I click on the link you pasted (http://www.bricklabels.com/), I end up at a GoDaddy landing page. Maybe you forgot to renew the domain??

Answer (score 1):

I would start with looking at the way [Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com) has their catalog organized, or look at [LDraw](http://www.ldraw.org)'s catalog. They have a fairly basic system segmenting LEGO into bricks, plates, tiles, beams, rods, minifigs etc. Should get you going.

EDIT: And if you really want to ID each part, just use the Bricklink part numbers (same as LDraw's numbers) to print on the bins. The Catalog feature should help you getting those, once you are familiar with the Bricklink naming schedule.

Comment: Hi;  I dont' want to ID mark every part, I want to ID mark every box where I put the certain item.

Comment: Ok - then never mind my edit.